# Re-push commit after failed push

Tags: git, push

I had problems pushing a commit yesterday, my Git installation must've been corrupt. Now I have a commit that my Git client think is pushed, but in reality is not.

How can I re-push this commit?

My git log looks something like this:

- Latest commit (exists on remote also)
- Some commit (exists on remote
  also)
- *Big commit (does not exist on remote)*
- Other commit (exists on remote
  also)

Comment: That scenario is rather unlikely because then the remote would be lacking a commit in the middle of history -- that would utterly confuse git. You should `git fetch` from the remote to make sure what you see is up to date, and look at the history with `gitk` or `git log --graph`; update your question with your findings

Comment: I would do "git fetch", and then do "git rebase". After that, you can do "git push" again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather start afresh, with:

- a new local clone of the remote repo.
- adding a remote to the first local clone of the repo, and fetching the commits into the new local repo
- cherry-picking the missing commit, applying it in the new repo, and then pushing back to the remote repo.

---

The [OP znarkus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138023/znarkus) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725476/re-push-commit-after-failed-push/14726587#comment20613676_14726587):

> Turned out to be an issue with my Git hosting

Comment: Turned out to be an issue with my Git hosting. Your solution would probably have worked though, thanks.

Comment: @Znarkus ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility. Could you share the (general) details about the issue and the resolution you had to take?